# Get unique factor values in a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Using starwars dataset for reproduciblity (looking for tidyverse solution)

I can use across to get number of unique values

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character),as.factor)) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.factor),n_distinct))
```

What I want is the actual data that these numbers represents, I understand that it wont be rectangular data because gender has 3 distinct values & sex has 5 (so on & so forth) but I am ok to have to extra spaces as NA or blank.

Looking for the final output to be a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to first count the max number of unique values in the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
max_len <- starwars %>% summarise(across(where(is.character),n_distinct)) %>% max
```

Once we have that we can use it to index ever column

```
starwars %>% summarise(across(where(is.character),~unique(.)[seq_len(max_len)]))

# A tibble: 87 x 8
#   name      hair_color  skin_color   eye_color sex      gender homeworld species  
#   <chr>     <chr>       <chr>        <chr>     <chr>    <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 Luke Sky… blond       fair         blue      male     mascu… Tatooine  Human    
# 2 C-3PO     NA          gold         yellow    none     femin… Naboo     Droid    
# 3 R2-D2     none        white, blue  red       female   NA     Alderaan  Wookiee  
# 4 Darth Va… brown       white        brown     hermaph… NA     Stewjon   Rodian   
# 5 Leia Org… brown, grey light        blue-gray NA       NA     Eriadu    Hutt     
# 6 Owen Lars black       white, red   black     NA       NA     Kashyyyk  Yoda's s…
# 7 Beru Whi… auburn, wh… unknown      orange    NA       NA     Corellia  Trandosh…
# 8 R5-D4     auburn, gr… green        hazel     NA       NA     Rodia     Mon Cala…
# 9 Biggs Da… white       green-tan, … pink      NA       NA     Nal Hutta Ewok     
#10 Obi-Wan … grey        pale         unknown   NA       NA     Bestine … Sullustan
# … with 77 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, Ronak this is exactly what I was looking for. I do not understand what happens after unique() though. Also, I was trying to run this
mtcars %>% mutate(across(mpg:cyl),.*0). For some reason it converts all of the columns to 0 instead of the first two. Any idea how can I run this for only first two columns

Comment: The function is the second argument in `across` so do `mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(mpg:cyl,~.*0))` to apply it to two columns.

Answer (score 1):

to return a data frame with length of unique values, use map_df

```
purrr::map_df(.x = starwars, .f = ~ length(unique(.x)))
```

to return a data frame with the actual unique values (padded with NAs), you can use:

```
map(.x = starwars, .f = unique) %>% 
  map(`length<-`, max(lengths(.))) %>% 
  as_tibble
```